# Entity Framework DBSet as combobox/list datasource

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, entity-framework, combobox

I need some desperate help with a small issue, which I believe its pretty easy for those seasoned programmers with years of experience in Entity Framework. This is my first experience with EF. I have a group of comboboxes that need to be filled on the Form_Load event. For the sake of refactoring and avoidance of code redundancy,  I made a function that all the combos invoke passing the necessary parameters to have it filled like this:

```
    private void FormEntities_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //string query = "Select Id, Name from Table_Name";
        FillCombo(cboCountry, "Select Id, Name from Country", "Name", "Id");
        FillCombo(cboCategory, "Select Id, Name from Category", "Name", "Id");

    }

    public void FillCombo(ComboBox combo, string query, string displayMember, string valueMember)
    {
        sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConStr);
        sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
        dt = new DataTable();
        sqlDa.Fill(dt);
        combo.DataSource = dt;
        combo.DisplayMember = displayMember;
        combo.ValueMember = valueMember;
        combo.Selected.Index = -1;
    }
```

Since I'm using now EF, I intend to use the same function to fill the comboboxes but this time, using EF Entities as my datasource, like seen below. The problem is, I don't know which Class/Type I should defined for my second parameter in the function to access  the DBSet collection.  I've tried the code below, but it just won't work. When I invoke the function, the compiler throws an error saying I've passed some invalid arguments. What am I doing wrong here?

```
    private void FormEntities_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    SystemDBContext ctxt = new SystemDBContext ();

        FillCombo(cboCountry, ctxt.CountryEntity, "Name", "Id");
        FillCombo(cboCategory, ctxt.CategoryEntity, "Name", "Id");
    }

    public void FillCombo(MetroFramework.Controls.MetroComboBox combo, DbSet datasource, string displayMember, string valueMember)
    {
        combo.DataSource = datasource.ToList();
        combo.DisplayMember = displayMember;
        combo.ValueMember = valueMember;
        combo.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the exact Exception you are facing?

Comment: The error is a compile time error: `'System.Data.Entity.DbSet' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Exactly, thats the error! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DbSet` class has no `ToList` method or extension method, You should create generic method to solve the problem:

```
public void FillCombo<T>(... , List<T> datasource, ...) where T:class
{
    combo.DataSource = datasource;
    ...
}
```

Then when you pass a `List<Category>` to the method, the type of T will be determined and would be `Category` and the same for `List<Country>`.

Here is some examples of calling the method:

```
FillCombo(..., context.Categories.ToList(), ...);
FillCombo(..., context.State.Where(st => st.CountryId.Trim() == id).ToList(), ...);
```

Comment: Hey Mr. Reza, you just made my day. Thanks a lot, its working properly. But, theres a issue I forgot to address in my first post. What if I have a combobox with a conditional filling, i.e., it should be filled when the category combo is filled. So I need to send the second parameter with a "where" clause to filter the result?

Comment: No problem, the basics of the answer is the same; you can set the type of datasource parameter as `List<T>` and always pass the result of your `Where(....).ToList()` to the `FillCombo` method. Let me know if you need a more detailed answer :)

Comment: Hi there! Once again, thanks for the effort to make my life easier. And sorry for the late reply, but technical difficulties prevented me from do it earlier. Back to the issue in hand, I'd like to let you know that only the first example of invoking the method works. On the second way, where I try a conditional combo filling the compiler complains, saying: The type arguments for method FillCombo<T>(Combo, DbSet<T>, string, string)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly. What am I missing here? Sorry if I'm not grasping the obvious!

Comment: If you read the edited answer, you will see I changed the parameter to be `List<T>`, so you should call `ToList()` outside of method on your dbset or your query, then pass it to method. For example when you want pass `Context.Categories` first make it to list: `Context.Categories.ToList()` and then pass it. Or when you want to pass a query, first make the query `.ToList()` and then pass it to the method.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Amazing. These are my first steps with EF, and knowing that its been around for years, make me  regret for not having started with it earlier. It really speeds up your code writing. I'll definitely need your help with a few more issues on EF. But I dont know if I should post a new question or if I can keep on here!!?

Comment: We should ask only one question in each thread and for more questions ask new question :-)

Comment: By the way, when a post answers your question you can mark it as accepted by click on check mark near the post. While you can accept only one answer, When you reached 15 reputation, you can vote for all useful answers includind the accepted one. You also can vote for good questions.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the enlightening. But for some strange reason, maybe because I'm new, the said check mark doesn't show. All I see is  "share, edit,delete, flag" options on the bottom and "mark as favourite" on the left side!!!??

Comment: You are welcome. The checkmark is at. left side of answer :)

Comment: [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/308647)